# replacement for the horizontal ruler <hr> tag

Tags: html, css

I'm using the below code to generate a horizontal bar. It works in older brower versions but not in the Internet explorer 9. It won't be visible until I click on 'Compatibility View'. Do we have an alternate for this or has it got replaced?

```
<hr style="color:#F87431 ; height:7px "/>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
<hr style="background:#F87431; border:0; height:7px" />
```

Answer (score 14):

HR in its original form, like STRIKE, B etc. were far too layout and presentation oriented.

HTML 5 is moving the markup towards a more semantic structure with more emphasis the layout being placed on CSS and media elements.

From the W3C documentation:

```
In HTML 4.01, the <hr> tag represented a horizontal rule. 
In HTML5, the <hr> tag defines a thematic break. 
However, the <hr> tag may still be displayed as a horizontal rule in visual browsers, but is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms.
```

So you just need to style it up nicely.

Answer (score 14):

I've also use div's for this, something like `<div style="width: 100%; height: 7px; background: #F87431; overflow: hidden;">`

Comment: Thanks buddy, saved my day. 
i was looking out for an alternative for <hr> thanks a lot

Answer (score -5):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="color:#F87431;height:7px;">-------------------</div>
```

Don't use the HR as it's deprecated at this stage, and only use inline CSS for testing ;-)

Comment: Changes in HTML5: Although previous versions of HTML defined the hr element only in presentational terms, the element has now been given the specific semantic purpose of representing a “paragraph-level thematic break”. see http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html

Comment: Still shouldn't be used at it looks horrible and devs maintaining your markup in the future will think it's okay to reuse if you've used it - and they may not style out its inherent ugliness. In practice, it's to be avoided.

Comment: Not deprecated and this is a horrible idea.